# Migration of EA server (Jaguar CTS - Sybase product)

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, sap-ase, easerver

I am currently using Jaguar CTS (also called as EA server, a Sybase product) for one of my Java based applications.

Does anyone know how to migrate Jaguar to other technologies.

I asked the same question in SAP forum, but did not got any reply.

This link explains about what [Jaguar CTS](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/42246) is.

Could someone please let me know if they have used/migrated from Jaguar CTS. Any reference on this would also be of great help.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAServer is just an application server like JBOSS or WebLogic. Your should not migrate the Application Server but your application. Now you have asked a question like: I have an application on Windows and I would like to migrate my Windows system to Linux.

This question should be asked to the vendor of your application that has been made. If you have an application written in Java then the task would easier, since there are other application servers that support Java applications. But it might require to rewrite some Java code since current versions might behave differently.

If you have a PowerBuilder application then you have to rewrite it to Java since no other application server beside EAServer supports them.

Comment: thanks for the information..have you migrated from EAServer to any other servers like Jboss etc..I want to know the migration steps and the precautions to be taken..

Comment: If you have a PowerBuilder component then the only way it is to rewrite it in Java. This is a complete different programming language.